# Disable display scaling on high DPI settings from a USB Stick Drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, vbscript, high-dpi

My question is very similar to other requests for disabling high DPI settings but mine has a bit of a twist.

I am using various USB stick drives to enact a script to 'reset' desktops to a certain look including a custom desktop using BGInfo.

This setup is working great as long as the BGInfo file is opened up and right click and select the 'disable' box in the compatibility tab.

I would like to add to the script a means to automatically disable the High DPI settigns for BGInfo but I am not sure exactly how to set the pathway to the file every time I put it into any given laptop.

I have so far:

```
 rem Disable high DPI settings for bginfo

 myKey = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\SIGN.MEDIA=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx Bginfo.exe"

 WshShell.RegWrite myKey,"HIGHDPIAWARE","REG_SZ"

 wshShell.Run "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\rundll32.exe 

 user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters"
```

where xxxxxxx= the serial number of the USB stick when doing a terminal command

```
lsblk --nodeps -o name,serial
```

This may be over engineering the problem.  The good news is that the USB stick will always be designated drive D in the laptops I am putting it into.

Any thoughts?

Dave

Comment: Which file is it?

Comment: Why don't you install `bginfo` on the USB sticks?

Comment: Running `where bginfo` in a cmd shell will tell you where it is installed. You can parse the output.

Comment: The file is bginfo.exe  which resides on the USB stick.  The whole script is on the USB stick with the goal of:

Comment: I would like to save myself the 'hassle' of having to right click Bginfo-> Properties-> Compatability -> Disable display scaling on high DPI settings. on the USB stick every stingle time.

Comment: I have everything set except that the Bginfo file on the stick will automatically tile the wallpaper so the messages show up 4 times and have tiny fonts.  Disabling high DPI setings *clicking on the box" will allow the text messages to be displayed the way we want them to.

Comment: The goal of the USB stick is to have the VBScript and files to clean the desktop of any improper icons, and set up a wallpaper that has a given Text Message posted on a blue background that has business related instructions or messages..  I use Bginfo on the USB stick to set up the text messages I want.